# How to add a key and value to end of array during a while statement

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to add a key value to an array that will have another array as it's value.

Code:

```
while($row=$checku->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $requested_data=array(
        "name"=>$row['from'],
        "title"=>$row['title'],
        "message"=>$row['message'],
        "time_post"=>$row['time_post']
    );
    $response["requested_data"]=$requested_data;
}
```

The issue is that it simply overwrites the last value with the current one being grabbed.  It outputs:

```
responseString: {"status":"ok","code":0,
"requested_data"
:{"name":"Admin Team","title":"Ripple","message":"no",
"time_post":""}}
```

The problem is there should be more than one `requested_data`

Suggestions, thoughts?

UPDATE:

If I take John's awesome awnser!  It still not exactly what I am looking for, I am re-encoding to `JSON` type and I need the key `requested_data` to also be recreated and not just add the array in the same key devided by a `,`

Here is what is outputted when using John's code:

```
responseString: {"status":"ok","code":0,"requested_data"
:[{"name":"Admin Team","title"
:"Ripple","message"
:"Testing this awesome application out!","time_post":"March 8"},{"name":"Admin Team","title"
:"Ripple","message":"no","time_post":""}]}
```

Notice how within `requested_data` there are now 2 array and that is great, except that I need that array to be out of the current `requested_data` and within another `requested_data`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `$response["requested_data"]` an array and then append to that array:

```
$response["requested_data"] = array();
while ($row = $checku->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $requested_data = array(
        "name" => $row['from'],
        "title" => $row['title'],
        "message" => $row['message'],
        "time_post" => $row['time_post']
    );
    $response["requested_data"][] = $requested_data;
}
```

Comment: Wait @JohnConde I need it to also recreate the same key not just divide it with a `,`